# Gnome shows workspace before showing the login screen

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, gnome

I have used Gnome for a long time and always have seen this problem. When I close the laptop lid and re-open it, it shows my workspace for 1 second or less and then shows the login screen.I use Fedora but I have seen it in Ubuntu too.

My expected behavior is not to show my workspace and windows, and to directly show the login screen.

Is it a bug? If not, Why does it have this behavior?

Comment: I have also witnessed it.

Comment: Ditto. This was not always the case though; I think I've only seen in in Ubuntu 10.10 or 11.04 until 11.10.

Answer (score 2):

> My expected behavior is not to show my workspace and windows, and to
>   directly show the login screen.

Yes, I agree -- that seems legitimate.  You should report this behavior.

> Is it a bug? If not, Why does it have this behavior?

I guarantee you that if you open a bug with your distro or gnome directly you'll get an explicit indication of whether or not it's a bug.  If you're lucky they'll explain why it has this behavior too.